# How to get local jar dependency in gradle

Tags: gradle

I am trying to build a 'lib' folder with all the dependencies from my projects. The thing is that I can get the list of all the artifacts with 'allModuleArtifacts' but my local JAR file is not listed there since it is not in the repository.

In my build.gradle for my project I have:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'jar', include: '*.jar')
```

I would like to know how to add that local file to the maven local repository or to list this kind of dependencies from a project.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the files of a configuration like this:

```
configurations.compile.files.each {
   println it
}
```

This will resolve the configuration and you are able to access all the files that have been downloaded. Including local file dependencies.

More infos here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html

Comment: This seems to not list my local jar. When I say local jar, I mean the jar that I have in a folder in my project. This only lists local maven and gradle cache files.

Comment: This works if I do it in the project which I want the dependencies. But I am trying to do it from another project which will gather all dependencies from all other projects. It's a build.gradle that lists all projects and their dependencies.

Comment: then simply wrap it in `allprojects { }`

Comment: It stils doesn't give me the local files. The classpath of each project does contains the .jar (with the path in the worksace/jar) instead of in the gradle cache or maven local.